# Does task queue(macro task queue) in Javascript Runtime Environment is a set data structure?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

> Task queues are sets, not queues, because step one of the event loop processing model grabs the first runnable task from the chosen queue, instead of dequeuing the first task.

This is mentioned on whatwg website [Link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-queue) and I am unable to understand that why set data structure is used instead of queue.

Comment: Note that the event-loop and task-queues are not the fact of the JS engine but of the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in order to get picked, the task has to be [runnable](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-task-runnable), and to be runnable, its document has to be fully active or null.

If they were actual [queues](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#queue), the distinction couldn't be done and tasks whose document is not fully active would get selected.

Comment: Do you have an example of a task "queue" set that contains tasks from different documents? I'd imagine that with "actual" queues you'd have one per document. (Or per browsing context? I never really got around to understand multi-document windows)

Comment: @Bergi I suppose that will depend on each task source, and some queues may indeed be specific for a single Document (e.g. I suppose message-queues are such), but for most, it should actually be one queue per event-loop so that the order between for instance a same-origin iframe and its owner document will be maintained. I guess that's actually observable. But honestly I'm also getting confused pretty quickly with these Navigables concepts.

Comment: @Bergi, So it is indeed [observable](https://jsfiddle.net/7pgkLyf6/) (check your browser's console), and, of course, not interoperable... Chrome seems to have a single queue per event-loop as per the specs, while Firefox seems to have one queue per document,  and Safari does its thing as per usual (though to be fair, their behavior isn't against the specs, they just prioritize the timer tasks from the iframe before the message task from the main, which is just *weird*, not *wrong*).