# Does browser really use micro task and macro task queue in event loop?

Tags: browser, event-loop

Edited the description, because I have read many articles introduced micro macro tasks model before so I thought it existed.

Here's original question
I've been reading through the HTML Standard, particularly the section on [event loops](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops), and I noticed that the documentation did not explicitly mentions "macro tasks." Instead, it describes that an event loop has one or more task queues, where a task queue is a set of tasks. So there could be multiple task queues.

Moreover, it states that the microtask queue is distinct and not considered a task queue. What does this mean?

Comment: "*no longer*" - did it ever?

Comment: "*I'm curious if this impacts the way we should understand or work with asynchronous JavaScript operations in web development*" - no, absolutely not. The concepts, our understanding of them, and the way we should work, does not change; even if the language used by the specification did.

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/71014496/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77012586/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67667045/1048572, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62128836/1048572 with answers from our resident html spec expert :-)

Comment: For the trivial, the earliest published document mentioning tasks would be https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090212/browsers.html#queue-a-task and it was already called "a task" and didn't mention "macro task" at all, nor "microtask" which would come [years later](https://searchfox.org/whatwg-html/rev/9e4e534ed1e4d67ffb0fffb7e8e0cb783a66a731/source#80329) and didn't introduce that term either. So nothing changed. Then for the rest of your question, I agree with the comment above, and I thus voted to close your question to the one that answers about why it's not a queue.

Comment: "*many articles introduced micro macro tasks model before so I thought it existed.*" - what makes you think it doesn't exist? Just because the spec does not use the exact terminology, it doesn't mean it's not the model that browsers implement. "*So there could be multiple task queues*" - sure, every good article on the event loop should have mentioned that events from different sources may be handled with different priorities.